# How to set MX records for Google Apps and for own Service

Tags: dns, gmail, google-apps, mx-record

I want to set MX records on my domain correctly. My problem is - Im using Google Apps for only one email, lets call it admin@xyz.com now I have installed Froxlor on my server (admin panel, mail service etc.) and now I want to create new email, lets call it contact@xyz.com on my server.

Here are my MX records for Google Apps on my domain:

```
(clear) MX ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.         1    3600
(clear) MX ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.    5    3600
(clear) MX ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.    5    3600
(clear) MX ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.      10   3600
(clear) MX ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.      10   3600
```

Now I want to add new MX record for my server and it should take 1. prio.

```
(clear) MX xyz.com 1 3600
```

So I had to change ASPMX from Google to "2".

Now Ive got a trouble with receiving Messages on my google email, but I can fully use my "server" account.

How do I have to set thous MX records to get it work.

Im really new in this, so I can do some mistakes, so sorry for that and for my bad English.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So, that's not how MX records work. Essentially, the first record is where all mail is going and any subsequent records are backups. For example, if `(clear) MX xyz.com 1 3600` failed for some reason, then all mail would go to Google's servers in the order you've specified in priority.

You're going to want to look into implementing [Split Delivery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/173534). This would mean that, you could have the following setup:

- MX Records pointed to Google
- Someone emails admin@xyz.com and it goes to their Apps mailbox
- Someone mails user@xyn.com and, because they don't have an Apps account, it's forward on to you legacy or secondary system

You can find a bit more information on Priorities on Google Support site [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125).

Hope this helps!